# Minimum energy orbit to send a projectile from Earth to Moon

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, projectile

I am given the following question:

[image]

I am wondering, isn't the orbit with the lowest energy is that simply of shooting the projectile directly into the moon?  The question suggests otherwise, since they explicitly asked for an "orbit" and there's actually a follow up question that suggests this is not the case.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Remember that the moon is a moving target. If you fire directly at the moon then by the time the projectile gets there the moon will have moved on and you'll miss. You need to aim ahead of the Moon in order to hit it.

Comment: Check out Hohman transfer orbits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohmann_transfer_orbit

Comment: If you watch the Apollo rockets lauching in the 1960's, you can see them tilting over as they climbed, so they were not in anyway pointed directly at the moon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a considerably more difficult problem than the asker anticipated.

The projectile must be able to reach a point at which the gravitational pull of Earth and Moon are equal. If it reaches this point with a small non-zero velocity it will fall to the Moon rather than fall back to Earth. If you launch horizontally you can make use of the spin velocity of the surface of the Earth relative to the orbiting Moon.

Comment: @sammy_gerbil but does that necessarily mean that the lowest energy orbit must be launched in the horizontal direction? Even if I launch it at an angle above the horizontal, the spin velocity will also play a role.  In other words, how should I prove that a lowest energy orbit must be launched horizontally?